# How to find out whether input is number or text in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, numbers, identification

I've tried to search, but I think my google is skill is not good enough, so I'm asking a help from people. I'm scanning through a string and taking each element. I need to find out whether it's number or text. I did my checking in that way:

```
// Try to convert to double
@try{
double whatever=[myString doubleValue];

// If text is stored in myString, then it should throw an exception
} @catch (NSException *e){

// Do whatever I need, but here I know that it's text, not a number


}
```

However I found out that Objective-C doesn't throw an exception, it just returns 0. I can't rely on the fact that user won't use zero as an input, what should I do?

Thanks in advance and I'm pretty sure there are treads like this, I just didn't find them...

Comment: I believe `NSScanner` is the best way to do this. See the answer by @VinceBurn

Comment: There is no need for the try/catch since calling `NSString doubleValue` will not throw an exception. This isn't Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:myString];

if (number) {
  // it's a number
} else {
  // it's not a number
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert to double and back to string. If it matches the source, then it was a double.
 Careful with leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Wow, how didn't I think about it... Thanks a lot!

Comment: And I found out that initial can be 21, but double value is going to be 21.000000... for example.. but good idea thought, I'll do some simple checks and will findout.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Floating point numbers aren't exact. Strings are.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to find out if you got a valid `double` with this method :

```
- (BOOL)scanDouble:(double *)doubleValue
```

once you have initialized your scanner with your string.

---

Why `(double *)` ?
Because you want the method to return to you 2 informations, `the doubleValue` and `is it a valid double`. The latter is given by the BOOL and for the former only a Pointer can get you a value out of a method call (apart from the return value)

> **Parameters**
>   doubleValue
>   Upon return, contains the scanned value. Contains HUGE_VAL or –HUGE_VAL on overflow, or 0.0 on underflow.
>   **Return Value**
>   YES if the receiver finds a valid floating-point representation, otherwise NO.

Comment: Thanks, but why pointer to a double, not a double itself? As far as I know double is a primitive type...

Comment: @AlexanderTroshchenko Because you want the method to return to you 2 informations, the doubleValue and is it a valid double. The latter is given by the BOOL and for the former only a Pointer can get you a value out of a method call

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString *stringElement = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[yourString length]];
for (int i=0; i<[yourString length]; i++) {
    if (isdigit([stringElement characterAtIndex:i])) {
      //is digit
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**

```
NSError* error;
NSString* string=@"10";
NSNumberFormatter* formatter=[NSNumberFormatter new];
formatter.numberStyle= NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle; // set whatever style you need
NSNumber* number;
if([formatter getObjectValue: &number forString: string errorDescription: &error])
{
    // You got the number
    NSLog(@"%@",number);
}
else
{
    // haven't got the number, the string is invalid
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```